# Using variables and functions in other fileis Node js

Tags: node.js, module

I have two separate files and I want to use functions and variables in my first file in another file.
What I mean is, here is the content of my first file:

```
const db = mongoose.connection;
```

and in my second file I need to for example log it:

```
console.log(db)
```

I used export and import but it did not work:

```
export const db = mongoose.connection;

import db from (./db.js)
console.log(db)
```

I got this error:
**SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module**

Comment: i send an answer read this and say it useful or not :)

Comment: i dont understand why it error happend.

Comment: i know the why now :) you should use a JS compiler like babel. read my answer edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in node js (or modern another js platforms) you can use modules.

in node js. you have 2 choice.

1: common js (CJS) modules:

```
in a way, nodeJS based on CJS. and CJS‌ modules builtin available in node.

you can imort a CJS‌ module with this code :

const module = required("module file widout .js");
```

and for create modules (in your module file) :

```
module.export = {your code};
```

2 ES6 modules :

```
es6 is a newer version of JS and that supports modules defaultly.
```

use module :

your example :)‌ (in question post) :

```
from module import a;
console.log(a); //1
```

create module :

```
export a = 1
```

***very important for ES6 modules:*** you should be use a js compiler, like babel to compile es6-21 to es5 nodeJS and browsers (i dont know other platforms) does not support es6 or above JS versions.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create the HTML file, too? If so try loading the second file in as a module type to fix the error.

Put this in your HTML file:

```
<script type="module" src="secondScript.js"></script>
```

Comment: this for DOM/web front end js. not for nodeJS